# Router Not Passing *Some* Requests

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, iptables, voip

Sometime yesterday, my Asterisk box quit talking to my voip provider.  I've determined it to be the router, as I have a mirrored router on standby should this one causes problems - which it did.

The router is running Ubuntu 10.04, kernel: 2.6.32-39-server.

I've pared down the iptables to bare minimum in the hopes that might be the problem:

```
*filter
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j LOG  --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_OUT:
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j LOG  --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_IN:
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j LOG  --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_OUT:
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j LOG  --log-level 7 --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_IN:
-A FORWARD -m state -i eth0 -o eth1 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state -i eth0 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport 4569 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed

*mangle
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 4569 -j DNAT  --to 192.168.1.23:4569
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5930 -j DNAT  --to 192.168.1.130:5900
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30 -j DNAT  --to 192.168.1.130:22
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10001 -j DNAT  --to 192.168.1.130:10000
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT  --to 192.168.1.130:8000
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 10001:20000 -j DNAT  --to 192.168.2.3:10001-20000
COMMIT
# Completed
```

I've even:

```
apt-get purge iptables
```

&

```
apt-get install iptables
```

I've tried connecting to the voip provider from another computer using Zoiper & that was blocked as well:

```
745 65.421743   174.34.146.162  192.168.1.105   ICMP    98  Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
```

I can also ping the IP and get a successful return:

```
root@pbx:~ $ ping atlanta.voip.ms
PING atlanta.voip.ms (174.34.146.162) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 174.34.146.162.rdns.ubiquityservers.com (174.34.146.162): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=26.1 ms
64 bytes from 174.34.146.162.rdns.ubiquityservers.com (174.34.146.162): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=28.8 ms
64 bytes from 174.34.146.162.rdns.ubiquityservers.com (174.34.146.162): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=25.7 ms
64 bytes from 174.34.146.162.rdns.ubiquityservers.com (174.34.146.162): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=27.9 ms
64 bytes from 174.34.146.162.rdns.ubiquityservers.com (174.34.146.162): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=23.9 ms

--- atlanta.voip.ms ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.934/26.542/28.848/1.734 ms
```

Using another network, I was able to connect successfully to the voip provider as well as when I swapped the router out for the back up.

Everything else I have checked seems to pass through ok.  I can connect from outside of the network to the PBX, and just about anything else I need to connect to.  It just seems that the router has taken a dislike to anything VOIP related.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SIP VoIP telephony, you have to use this `iptables` command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
```

This is for SIP messages. You will need some ports for voice packets too:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I'm using IAX2, which uses port 4569.  Switching to SIP just made it more problematic while trying to diagnose.

Comment: @Go3Team are IAX using UDP? Hmm... I've found, that yes. Try capture packets and see, what packets sending your Asterisk and if it got responses.